# jquery toggle auto height

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to make a box that can be expanding height by click button.
The box show just 3 rows of the text as default. (Lets say.. height is 50px and overflow Hidden)

When I click on the "More" button, animate the box text to slidedown. Another click to Slide up.

Also I would like to slide to the "auto" height!!  (Slidedown depends on content height)
I tried many jquery samples, but failed.  Someone help me please?

Here is my code...

```
<div class="cmCnt">
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
AAA<br>
</div>


<a href="#" class="btnMore">more</a>


.cmCnt { height:50px;  overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Please post the code *that you have tried* so far, so we can see your logic and help you understand it rather than just code it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this is a problem I ran into a few years back... My solution was to start with no special styles (i.e. `auto` height, `visible` overflow), then store the full height of the element using javascript. Next, change the height to 50px and overflow to hidden AFTER the page loads (with no transition). Now, you know what the full height is, and you can animate to it at will.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cmCnt').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('originalHeight', $(this).height();
        $this.css({'height': '50px', 'overflow': 'hidden'});
        $this.click(function() {
            var newHeight = $this.data('originalHeight');
            // animate $this to newHeight however you like here
        });
    ));
));
```